# AIX memory utilization

Tags: unix, system, aix, system-administration

I am new in AIX and I want to learn about how memory utlization works in AIX
I can use nmon and where it shows Memory as below.

As it shows total memory is 128GB and used memory is 124GB Is it normal/ I want to learn how to make sure reading the below information we are okay with memory utilization

---

│          Physical  PageSpace |        pages/sec  In     Out | FileSystemCache                                                                                                                               │
│% Used       97.2%      0.9%  | to Paging Space   0.0    0.0 | (numperm)  6.6%                                                                                                                               │
│% Free        2.8%     99.1%  | to File System    0.0    0.0 | Process   77.7%                                                                                                                               │
│GB Used     124.4GB     0.7GB | Page Scans        0.0        | System    12.9%                                                                                                                               │
│GB Free       3.6GB    79.3GB | Page Cycles       0.0        | Free       2.8%                                                                                                                               │
│Total(GB)   128.0GB    80.0GB | Page Steals       0.0        |           ------                                                                                                                              │
│                              | Page Faults      10.0        | Total    100.0%

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You want to consider the share of memory tied to FileSystemCache(numperm) and lruable in the nmon output. This is all stuff occupying otherwise unsued memory that can be cheaply evicted (e.g. filesystem buffers).    It is very similar to the +/- line for buffers/cache if you're familiar with /usr/bin/free on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for AIX to use up most of its memory, and it doesn't release memory as quickly as compared to other OSes. All of these are taken care by AIX's Virtual Memory Manager (VMM) and the `lrud` kernel process. The VMM's behavior can be tuned by using the `vmo` command.

In AIX there are two types of files put in memory - computational (i.e. executable files and their working area); and non-computational files (i.e. filesystem caches).

When AIX needs more memory, the `lrud` process is executed to steal memory. The type of files in memory, which the `lrud` will remove from memory, is determined by these VMM parameters - `minperm(%)`, `maxperm(%)`, and `lru_file_repage`. The `vmo` command can be used to make changes to these parameters.

Below shows type of files removed from memory by the `lrud`.

> If `numperm(%)` (*non-computational files cache*) is higher than `maxperm(%)`;
>   `lrud` will remove non-computational files.
>
> If `numperm(%)` is lower than `minperm(%)`; `lrud` will remove either > computational or non-computational file pages, whichever is least recently used.
>
> If `numperm(%)` is between `minperm(%)` and `maxperm(%)` and
>   `lru_file_repage` is '1'; non-computational pages will be removed if
>   it is lesser than computational pages. Otherwise if `lru_file_repage`
>   is '0': only non-computational pages will be removed.

To determine if AIX is having memory issues, I would look at the ratio of pages scanned and pages freed (*I cannot remember where is this in the nmon output*). If this ratio has a high value, it shows that the `lrud` is scanning a lot of pages to find pages to remove from memory.

---

*Disclaimer: My answer is based on AIX version 5.3 - 6.0 which I worked on in my previous company 3 - 4 years ago. But I doubt there might be significant change in the behavior of the `lrud` and VMM parameters in newer versions of AIX.*